eslint errors with TypeScript prototype function
I'm adding eslint v9 to my TypeScript project, starting with the standard rule set:
eslint.configs.recommended,
...tseslint.configs.strict,

I'd like to keep the rules quite strict, but I'm getting issues with the many prototype (extension) functions I have written.  As an example, see this code:
interface MyObject {
    name: string
}
declare global {
    interface Array<T> { // Error 1: 'T' is defined but never used.
        add(this: Array<MyObject>): void
        add(this: Array<MyObject>, withName: string | null): void // Error 2: These overloads can be combined into one signature with an optional parameter.
    }
}
Array.prototype.add = function(withName: string | null = null) {
    let obj = this; // Error 3: Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to local variable.
    if (obj.length > 100) { obj = []; }
    obj.push({ name: withName ?? 'default name' })
}

This is implementing an add function that can be used on an array of MyObject.  You can optionally supply a name and if the array gets too big it will reset.
There are three separate issues, but all with the same code - so I'm asking in one go!
Error 1 - @typescript-eslint/no-unused-vars
Array needs to define a type (T), but as the functions should only actually accept MyObject, T is never used.
Error 2 - @typescript-eslint/unified-signatures
Functions definitions in the interface cannot have default values, and if I remove the first definition, I can no longer call the function with a parameter.
Error 3 - @typescript-eslint/no-this-alias
this = [] causes the error The left-hand side...must be a variable, so aliasing is required.  This is a bit contrived above; a real function in code:
String.prototype.replacePlaceholders = function(strings: string[]): string {
    let s = this; // Error 3: Unexpected aliasing of 'this' to 
    for (let i = 0; i < strings.length; i++) {
        s = s.replace(`$${i}`, strings[i]);
    }
    return s.toString();
}

Maybe there is a better way to right my code; which I'd love to do if that is the case.  Or I could disable the rules; but if the code is correct, surly eslint should not raise an error.
Is it me or eslint?  If it's not me I'll raise an issue, but wanted to ask about my code first!

Error 1: this exposes a design issue. That method should really not live on the Array prototype if it requires a specific type. Error 2: you are not supposed to add a default value, just declare the parameter as optional: withName?: string | null. Error 3: obj = [] just doesn't make sense, it's not used elsewhere. You could write const obj = this.length > 100 ? [] : this; but really I'd write if (this.length > 100) return; this.push(…);.

Thanks for your comment.  Error 1: I agree, but how else can I achieve the same result?  Error 2: Perfect; that is the answer – my code is so much cleaner now!!  Error 3: You've taken my example too literally; I've added a real function to demonstrate the problem

Re 1: Just make a global function addMyObject(arr: MyObject[], withName?: string | null) instead of an array method. You shouldn't be able to write anyArray.add(), and you shouldn't modify Array.prototype anyway. Re 3: for that, just disable the rule (globally or for that line).
